# mysql centOS 6 Error Downloading Packages:

Tags: ssh, centos, mysql

Please help me... I am getting this error

Error Downloading Packages:
  mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686: Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/i386/6/updates/packages
    * free   0
    * needed 8.8 M
  mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686: Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/i386/6/updates/packages
    * free   0
    * needed 903 k
  mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686: Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/i386/6/updates/packages
    * free   0
    * needed 1.2 M

Comment: Someone else already answered this question here: http://serverfault.com/a/145086

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted unnecessary files. This occurs because I don't have enough space.

I just let my self to get panic. My bad.